# R generates error when using the if statement and for loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

The following is a data frame

```
   brand  production_cost  sell
   A      220               3
   B      180               1
   C      200               2
   D      240               4
   E      270               7
   F      200               4
```

If `sell > 3` then `investment = sell * production_cost`

If `sell < 3` then `investment = sell * 0.5 * production_cost`(50% of production cost)

I have tried by the following way:

```
   data <- read.table("Z:\\who.txt",header=TRUE)

   investment <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)

  for(i in 1:6){
    if(data$sell[i]>3){
      investment[i] <- sell[i] * production_cost
    }else {
      investment[i] <- sell[i] * 0.5 * production_cost
    }
  } # end for loop
```

But the error is object `sell` not found

Then I have to compute

If `investment >= 800` then `produce = 1`

If `investment < 800` then `produce = 0`

Though I couldn't compute the variable investment I supposed it is  as [by using calculator]

```
   investment <- c(330,90,200,960,1890,800)
   produce <- cut(investment,c(-Inf,800,Inf),labels=c("0","1"))
```

Here the problem is `investment[6]=800`. my attempt was to label it as `1`. But it is labeling as `0.`

Next i have to find the number of brands which are `produce=1`.

I tried this by the following way:

```
  sum=0

  for(i in 1:6){
    if(produce[i]==1)sum=sum+1
  } # end for loop
```

Is this right procedure and is there better way?

Comment: `sell` and `production_cost` do not exist but `data$sell` and `data$production_cost` do. post dput(data) so this is reproducible. look at `?ifelse`

Comment: Tip: `within(data, investment <- sell * production_cost * ifelse(sell>3, 1, 0.5))`

Comment: Given this and your previous question, you may want to start by reading http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf, and start with Section 6.3 regarding dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *within*, it creates an environment and returns a new dataframe:

```
newdata = within(data, {
investment = ifelse(sell > 3, sell * production_cost, sell * production_cost *0.5 )
})

newdata = within(newdata, {
    produce = ifelse(investment >= 800, 1, 0)
})
```

NOTE: this code sets

```
 investment = sell * production_cost * 0.5
```

if sell == 3

Hope it helps.

Comment: why doesn't here `with` work? and sometimes the `expr` argument of `within` works without braces and sometimes doesn't. Why?

Comment: see ?with. Basically *with* returns the evaluated expression while *within* returns the modified dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your dataframe is `sample`. Following code is not tested

```
#You can use `ifelse` for first two problem

 sample$investment<-with(sample, ifelse(sell>3,sell * production_cost,sell * 0.5 * production_cost))
 sample$produce<-with(sample,ifelse(investment>=800,1,0))

#subset the sample with produce equal to 1 for part 3 and then use ddply from plyr to #count the number of brands

samplesub<-subset(sample, produce==1)

#number of brands 

install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
num_brand<-ddply(samplesub, .(brand), summarize, freq=length(brand))

#Alternative to `ddply` from plyr package
#Rather than using the `plyr` package, you can use the following simple code for part 3
num_brand<-with(samplesub,table(brand))
```

Comment: *plyr* is too much overhead for this simple task. Use *plyr* to do complex stuff with your data.

Comment: @Fernando : I will leave that to OP to decide.